# How can I store the Postgresql data on the EBS Volumes and not on the Root Volume?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-ebs

My PostgreSQL database is currently stored in the cloud. Normally, when creating a PostgreSQL database, all the data is stored on the root volume of the EC2 instance.

How can I make sure all the PostgreSQL data stored on the EBS volumes and not the root volume?

Comment: The root volume already **is** an EBS volume unless you chose an instance-store AMI.

Comment: @ceejayoz that is correct, however when installing postgresql and creating a database, it naturally stores all that data on the root volume, how can I configure it so that all the data is stored on the other EBS volumes?

Comment: `data_directory ` in your .conf file. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the help ceejayoz, much appreciated!